# Add a parameter in a SQL Server linked connection

Tags: sql-server

```
select @dbName="DBNAME"

select Distributorid  from [180.552.528.854,21414].[@dbName].DBO.DistributorMaster where Distributorid =XXXXXX
```

> ERROR: The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked
>   server[180.552.528.854,21414] does not contain the table
>   ""@dbName"."DBO"."DistributorMaster"". The table either does not exist
>   or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Comment: `declare @dbName varchar(50) = 'DBNAME';` Declare Local variable

Comment: Dynamic sql only.

Comment: have declared   already

Answer (score 4):

Try This. 
Dynamic variable value query .

```
            declare 
            @dbname nvarchar(max) ='dbName',


            @query nvarchar(max) ='select Distributorid  from [180.552.528.854,21414].[@dbName].DBO.DistributorMaster 
            where Distributorid =XXXXXX'

            SET @Query=REPLACE(@Query,'@dbname',@dbname)

            --print(@Query)

            execute SP_executesql  @Query
```

Answer (score -1):

When querying the Linked Server, you need to specify the fully qualified table name in the following pattern:

```
SERVER.DATABASE.SCHEMA.OBJECT
```

In addition to this, please check whether the table is listed on the Linked Server  with the help of SQL Server Management Studio, under the `Linked Servers`.

**EDIT:**
Please check [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=164892) site, if you've implemented all the steps noted on this site completely.

And also a common point that should've been missed is the following:

Adding `", @datasrc=@ServerName"` to your `sp_addlinkedserver` statement.

Comment: yes all is working but when ever i use parameter its throw error